# How to show Super Script characters in angular material tooltip?

Tags: angular-material, angular8

I have a text like below

```
Treatment-Emergent Adverse Events <sup>a</sup> Terms Suggestive of Abuse Potential Leading to Study or Study Drug Discontinuation by Decreasing Frequency Safety Analysis Set
```

while showing it in matTooltip , tooltip text is showing as `a` but it should `a` as superscript character. but it is showing `a` as it is in the string.
How to resolve it.

Comment: Try using <i> tag and see if it works. I don't think MatToolTip allow html as message.

Comment: not working i am getting the text from API response